How is it possible that my public IP is different everytime I check it?
C:\Users\user>curl ifconfig.me
177.238.21.18
C:\Users\user>curl ifconfig.me
177.238.22.31
C:\Users\user>curl ifconfig.me
177.238.21.162
C:\Users\user>curl ifconfig.me
177.238.22.250
C:\Users\user>curl ifconfig.me
177.238.20.119
C:\Users\user>curl ifconfig.me
177.238.21.20
C:\Users\user>curl ifconfig.me
177.238.23.127

No matter how many times I check my public ip, with whatever tool, it changes each time. I noticed this when I became unable to log into programs and websites that checked for a new IP. I did the email verify and it kept complaining that I was at a new location.
All the devices in my home exhibit this behavior. After switching to cellular data (a different ISP) it stops. Switching back to home internet it resumes. I restarted the router.

In addition to the already posted answer, see if you can switch to IPv6, that might eliminate your issue.

@LPChip Thank you. I hadn't thought of looking into that.

Your home internet provider likely uses CGNAT.
It works much like normal NAT, where your devices don't get their own public IPv4 addresses but have to "share" the router's – but CGNAT extends this so that even your router doesn't get its own public address anymore; instead you're now sharing public IP addresses with other customers.
Usually an ISP sets up CGNAT when they run out of IPv4 addresses to give out – which have gotten expensive recently, to the point that it can be cheaper to buy equipment for doing CGNAT than to buy more addresses. (In the past an ISP could simply ask for another chunk, but not anymore.)
It seems that your ISP chose to not implement "sticky" NAT assignments (maybe they're really short on addresses), so with every new TCP connection you make, the CGNAT equipment picks out a new public address at random.

CGNAT is not nice, but is good enough for most users provided it is "sticky". Being non-sticky makes it pretty unusable (as the poster noticed). Unfortunately the only solution is getting the ISP to give you a sticky or real ip-address (if that is an option and probably at a higher price) or getting another ISP that is better behaved.

@Jaromanda Router IP is 10.115.65.69 and its gateway is 10.115.64.1

@Tonny Thanks. I will talk to them.

@JasonJ.AyalaP. 10.x.x.x also means CGNAT. Those are "private space" addresses so there has to be a NAT involved further upstream (at the ISP) to convert these to real public p-addresses,

Why should this be strange? Most home internet connections use dynamic IP addresses, this means your public IP address can change over time. This is because your internet service provider (ISP) temporarily assigns you an IP address from a pool. They do this to manage their available addresses more efficiently and for minor security benefits. Things like your router restarting or your ISP's lease time expiring can trigger an IP address change. If you need a fixed address find out from them if you can purchase a static IP.

I don't think the usage of dynamic IP addresses is the issues here, but the speed at which new dynamic addresses get created.

It's strange because most such things do not occur as frequently as OP shows – routers do not restart every minute, nor do DHCP leases expire that fast; ISPs have an interest in letting the (traditional) IP address assignments last long enough that the change wouldn't interrupt active connections.
